# Update row in a table based on multiple rows in another table

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have two tables: **table1** and **table2**:

- **table1** has columns *id* and *integer*
- **table2** has columns *id* and *boolean*
- **table2** can have multiple rows with the same *id*

I want to update the *integer* column of **table1** by looking at all rows with the same *id* in **table2** and seeing if any of the *boolean* values are true. If so I want *table1.integer* to be 1, else I want it to be 0.

I have tried something like this:

```
UPDATE table1, 
(
   SELECT table2.id, Sum(table2.boolean) > 0
) AS 'condition' 
from     table2 
WHERE    1 
GROUP BY table2.id) table3 
SET table1.integer =IF(table3.condition, 1, 0) where table1.id = table3.id
```

And it seems to work, but I wanted to ask if there is a nicer/cleaner/more succinct way of updating the rows of **table1** according to multiple rows of **table2**.

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using. Then see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What RDBMS are you really using, you tag 2 here (I have removed them). The above looks like you're trying to `UPDATE `the values of 2 tables at the same time (one via a subquery); a DDL operation can only effect 1 object at a time, not many, and it can't reference a subquery (though you can create updatable CTEs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend `EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
    SET t1.integer = (EXISTS (SELECT 1
                              FROM table2 t2
                              WHERE t2.id = t.id AND
                                    t2.boolean
                             )
                     );
```

This can take advantage of an index on `table2(id, boolean)`.  With such an index, it should be faster than an approach that uses `JOIN` and `AGGREGATION`.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your query is MySql like, so you can do a join like this:

```
UPDATE table1 t1 INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id, MAX(boolean) maxboolean
  FROM table2
  GROUP BY id
) t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
SET t1.integer = t2.maxboolean
```

If there are `id`s in `table1` without a corresponding `id` in `table2` and you want the `integer` column for them to be updated to `0` then use a `LEFT` join:

```
UPDATE table1 t1 LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT id, MAX(boolean) maxboolean
  FROM table2
  GROUP BY id
) t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
SET t1.integer = COALESCE(t2.maxboolean, 0)
```